# How do i make profiles of people's contingent decisions in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, tree, statistics

Suppose a carpenter creates a wooden maze which from a birds eye view looks like a tree structure with nodes and branches. You start at a node which branches into 4 other nodes and each of those nodes branch again into 4 nodes, which branch one final time into 4 exits. This means you have 4x4x4=64 ways of finishing the maze.

Then I run hundreds of thousands of mice through this maze, and record the path they take by noting the branch path they choose at each node. Most mice will run the maze multiple times, and ofcourse they could choose a different path each time.

**Sample Data**

```
id    node1   node2     node3     date
"4"   "path1"  "path1"  "path4" "1999.01.01"
"9"   "path1"  "path3"  "path1" "1999.01.01"
"24"  "path1"  "path3"  "path2" "1999.01.01"
"1"   "path4"  "path3"  "path3" "1999.01.02"
"9"   "path2"  "path3"  "path1" "1999.01.02"
"22"  "path3"  "path3"  "path2" "1999.01.04"
...
```

I want to build a profile for each mice. So If im at a node arrived at by taking path 1 and then path 3, I can immediately use this to look up the data of mice #333 and find:

```
path1: 4 path2: 0 path3: 1 path 4: 10 Last_Chosen_Path:path3 Last_time_for_this_mice_to_arrive_at_this_position: 2002.05.01
```

where the number after each path is the number of times the mice has chosen to go through those paths. I would also like there to be information on the path chosen the last time said mouse arrived at this intersection as well as the date of the last time the mouse arrived at this position.

I've thought about this problem for a while and the best way i've come up with storing this in a dataframe where each column is the data on a single mice and each row is the path to arrive at every possible node for example 'path1.path2'. I can create 2 of these dataframes, one to store the frequency of each visit, the other would hold the dates, such that [row path1.path1, col = 'mice 333'] will be the date mouse 333 chose path 1 after choosing path 1 initially.

I would like to maybe find a potentially better way to sort things. Is there maybe a data strucuture like a tree with a dataframe at every node? That way, I can use the dataframe at the specific node to store data on the decision of mice that arrived there.

Secondly, is there a way to maybe make the storing more efficient since in most cases, the mice will pick similar paths and leave a majority of paths unexplored.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: what do you mean? is df referring to the dataset of the mice or the dataframe I have in mind of creating?

Comment: Of the mice. And expected output is also a good idea but apparently we would have some freedom to devise something.

Comment: I think i've provided an example of that in the question. I'll include a few more examples and tidy up the typing, but the whole dataset would look pretty much like that. it would be a dataframe with those headers.